# How to resolve "expected end" error in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, url

I am trying to make this code work in vba excel however i keep receiving Expected End error

```
URL_Last = "&amp;entry.7170534=" &amp; EmpID &amp; "&amp;entry.634952910=" &amp; EmpName &amp; "&amp;entry.1900852350=" &amp; Gender &amp; "&amp;entry.776101390=" &amp; Designation &amp; "&amp;entry.1211978069=" &amp; Address &amp; "&amp;submit=Submit"


Form_URL = URL_First &amp; URL_Last
```

May i ask what adjustment should i do inorder to fix this? Thanks

Comment: `&` is used to concatenate strings not `&amp;` (looks like a copy/paste error from HTML) so try replacing `&amp;` with `&`

Comment: Trying to add ampersand hence &amp; was used. Was there other way to add the ampersand?